# ¿ Cómo reemplazar sub-cadenas por otras sub-cadenas, de distinto tamaño?

Tags: c++

buen día, lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo un código para hacer tablas de verdad con sentencias que ingrese el usuario. Una parte del código tiene que comprobar si es una "fbf" (fórmula bien formada), para eso se tiene que hacer una serie de pasos, el primero es reemplazar todas las letras proposicionales por 0 (en esta parte utilice la función `strchr()` para reemplazar las `p` y `q` por `0`), para eso utilice este código:

```
char str[] = "This is a sample string";
char * pch;
cout<<"\n buscando s en "<<str<<endl;
pch=strchr(str,'s');
while (pch!=NULL){
    cout<<"\n encontrado en el indice : "<<pch-str<<endl;
    pch=strchr(pch+1,'s');
}
```

Que imprime este resultado:

```
buscando s in "This is a sample string"...
encontrado en el indice: 4
encontrado en el indice: 7 
encontrado en el indice: 11
encontrado en el indice: 18
```

Como pueden ver el código lee todas los caracteres 's' e imprime la posición. El código que aplique simplemente reemplaza esas posiciones dentro de la cadena por `0`. A diferencia de otros (con las misma función `strchr()`) que lee solo un caracter.
Para el segundo paso hay que reemplazar el término: `¬(0)` por `0`, para eso estoy tratando de utilizar la función `strstr()` (que como sabrán lee una cadena de caracteres dentro de otra). Trate de usar el mismo código de arriba, reemplazando obviamente lo necesario:

```
char str[] = "This is a sample string is, or is";
char * pch;
cout<<"\n buscando s en "<<str<<endl;
pch=strstr(str,"is");
while (pch!=NULL){
    cout<<"\n encontrador en el indice : "<<pch-str<<endl;
    str[pch-str]='1';
    //str[(pch-str)+1]='1';
    pch=strstr(pch+1,"is");
}
cout<<"\n -sentencia : "<<str<<endl;
```

Lo que me imprime es: `Th1s 1s a sample string 1s, or 1s`. Como pueden ver, este código pues si lee todas las cadenas `is`, pero solo reemplaza el primer índice. Hay varias formas de que me lea todos los índices, pero los reemplazaría todos por `1`, pero lo que yo necesito es que me reemplace toda la cadena `is` por `1`.
 Ya estuve buscando e implementando alternativas pero no me dan el resultado que busco. Una opción era usar la función `strcpy()` pero no me funciono (tal vez sea de esa forma pero la implemente mal, no se).

Les agradecería mucho si alguien sabe como solucionarlo.

Comment: La pregunta está etiquetada como C, pero usas `cout`, que es propio de C++... ¿Qué etiqueta es la correcta?

Comment: C++, creo que alguien la edito, no se porque.
Pero como ya me ha pasado, ya pude lograrlo!! =)

Comment: ¿Y es imprescindible usar `char[]`?